# C# equality with list-based properties

Tags: c#, .net

I've read numerous articles related to proper equality in C#:

http://www.loganfranken.com/blog/687/overriding-equals-in-c-part-1/

[What is the best algorithm for an overridden System.Object.GetHashCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode)

Assume the following sample class:

```
public class CustomData
{
    public string Name { get; set;}

    public IList<double> Values = new List<double>();
}
```

Would it still be the case to compare the **Values** property using **.Equals()**? Here is a full equality sample of what I mean:

```
#region Equality

    public override bool Equals(object value)
    {
        if(Object.ReferenceEquals(null, value)) return false;   // Is null?
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(this, value)) return true;   // Is the same object?
        if (value.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;    // Is the same type?

        return IsEqual((CustomData)value);
    }

    public bool Equals(CustomData obj)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;    // Is null?
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;     // Is the same object?

        return IsEqual(obj);
    }

    private bool IsEqual(CustomData obj)
    {
        return obj is CustomData other
            && other.Name.Equals(Name)
            && other.Values.Equals(Values);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            // Choose large primes to avoid hashing collisions
            const int HashingBase = (int) 2166136261;
            const int HashingMultiplier = 16777619;

            int hash = HashingBase;
            hash = (hash * HashingMultiplier) ^ (!Object.ReferenceEquals(null, Name) ? Name.GetHashCode() : 0);
            hash = (hash * HashingMultiplier) ^ (!Object.ReferenceEquals(null, Values) ? Values.GetHashCode() : 0);
            return hash;
        }
    }

    public static bool operator ==(CustomData obj, CustomData other)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(obj, other)) return true;
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;    // Ensure that "obj" isn't null

        return (obj.Equals(other));
    }

    public static bool operator !=(CustomData obj, CustomData other) => !(obj == other);

#endregion
```

Comment: I think `other.Values.Equals(Values);` should instead be `other.Values.SequenceEqual(Values);`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I made my changes to 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`List<T>.Equals(List<T> other)` will compare references. If you want equality for property `Values` to be defined as identical sequences of `doubles`, use the `IEnumerable<TSource>.SequenceEqual.(IEnemerable<TSource> other)` method ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567(v=vs.110).aspx)). See a refactored version of your `IsEqual(CustomData obj)` below:

```
private bool IsEqual(CustomData obj)
{
    return obj is CustomData other
        && other.Name.Equals(Name)
        && other.Values.SequenceEqual(Values);
}
```